# Please install kpsewhich and put it on path - error using LATEX with Xournalpp snap

Tags: command-line

In Xournal++ I want to use `Tools` -> `Add/Edit Tex` But I get

> Could not find kpsewhich in PATH; please install kpsewhich and put it on path.

I checked, it is installed

```
$ whereis kpsewhich
kpsewhich: /usr/bin/kpsewhich /usr/share/man/man1/kpsewhich.1.gz
```

But on

```
$ PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/kpsewhich:/usr/share/man/man1/kpsewhich.1.gz
$ xournalpp
```

I still get the error message above.

**UPDATES:**
I checked `echo $PATH` and `/usr/bin` is already on the path.

Comment: The `PATH` elements are directories to be searched for executables, NOT actual filenames! `/usr/bin` should already be in your `$PATH`, unless you've trashed it. `echo $PATH`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same issue as you. I was using the snap package of [xournalpp](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp).

First remove the snap package.
`sudo snap remove xournalpp`

After removing that package and installing it from the *bleeding edge* [PPA repository](https://launchpad.net/%7Eandreasbutti/+archive/ubuntu/xournalpp-master), latex worked just fine.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:andreasbutti/xournalpp-master
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xournalpp
```

If you want to stick to the latest stable version, you can instead use the *stable releases* [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eapandada1/+archive/ubuntu/xournalpp-stable).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/xournalpp-stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xournalpp
```